# Python Beautiful Soup 4 - finding element by class and aria-label

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to find an element with a particular class name and aria-label using Beautiful Soup 4. More specifically, I am scrapping an HTML code where each item on the list has the same class (`nd-list__item in-feat-item`) but a different aria-label (e.g. `aria-label="rooms"`). Source code below:

[image: Source code of the specific HTML. I am interested in quering each element by the class and aria-label together]

I have to search for a specific combination of class and aria-label because if I am unable to find it, I must return a `None` value (e.g. if there is none `<li .... aria-label="rooms"></li>` I must return `None`. Using `bs_object.find_all` method on the whole list and then iterating over each of the list elements is rather inefficient, as some listings may have different orderings (e.g. if there are no numbers of rooms provided, then the first element will be `"aria-label="surface"`) -> so I must be able to query directly whether the particular element is contained in the bs object.

Do you have some recommendations on how to do that without going in for `bs_object.find_all('li', class_='nd-list_item in-feat__item')` and then iterating over the whole list? I also thought about searching for the parent `<ul></ul>` tag and then using Regex - but it is also an overly complicated procedure. Thanks in advance for all the answers!

Comment: Show us your code: what have you tried until now?

Comment: use  `.find`  with the [`attrs` argument](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#kwargs) or [`.select`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) with [CSS selectors](https://facelessuser.github.io/soupsieve/selectors/basic/#attribute-selectors)